# Modify a value and write JSON to a file

Tags: java, json

I am trying to modify a JSON and write the modified JSON to a file. But the output file to which JSON was written was empty.

```
{
    "id": 4051,
    "name": "menad",
    "livelng": 77.389849,
    "livelat": 28.6282231,
    "creditBalance": 127,
    "myCash": 10
}
```

I want to update "**creditBalance**" value and write the JSON to a new File.

```
private static void readJs(String path) throws IOException, JSONException {
    File file = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(buffer);
    String json  = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    jsonObject.put("creditBalance",78);                   //  <-  Updating a value
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.json");
    fw.write(jsonObject.toString());
}
```

Comment: have you tried closing the file?

Comment: You'd need to flush the changes which should happen automatically if the writer is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

1. Call the `flush()` method on your FileWriter object, which will cause it to actually write out the contents of its buffer, or
2. Call the `close()` method to close the FileWriter, which will cause it to flush automatically before closing.

Option 2 is the best choice if you are finished writing to this particular file.  You should always be careful to close resources (like files) when you've completed operating on them.

Answer (score 1):

You lacked close filewriter:

fw.close();

It have to close